# Hiding videos on android sd card

Tags: android, video, sd-card

I am playing videos locally from sd card in listview in an android app. Now i want to hide those videos from user so that he can only play those videos but should not locate those videos to copy from sd card. Is there any way to hide videos on sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent access to files on external storage.

You can encrypt those videos so that only you can decrypt & play them.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion LAS_VEGAS. I was also thinking about encryption. LOS_VEGAS have you any idea how to encrypt videos?

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing prevents from the user rummaging around the SD card themselves either by ejecting and plugging into another machine, or putting the phone into mass storage/mtp mode. If you don't want the user to get their hands on the video, then don't store the video on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Storing on internal storage with Private permissions will at least keep the video only in your app.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```